# How to upload a ScheduledEvent cover using py-cord / discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I understand from the [API docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#scheduledevent) that there's no way to upload an image when creating the scheduled event, but the `edit()` has a `cover` argument, so there must be way to at least add it later. The docs say it takes an `Asset()`, but I don't understand how to create such asset from e.g. a PNG file. Seems like it works in a different way than sending an image with an `Embed()` as an attachment.

I'm using the [py-cord](https://pypi.org/project/py-cord/), but I think [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) should be similar or the same, I believe scheduled events is something that has been in the discord.py codebase before it was forked.

Comment: `Asset` will need a url. So you'll have to upload it somewhere (discord itself will work) and use that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing is specific for py-cord. Things are different in discord.py, with different names.

The `cover` argument accepts bytes of the image to be uploaded. There was a bug in the documentation, which made me think that it accepts an `Asset`. I found it out by reading the code directly and I've [sent a fix](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/pull/1667) so that the argument is documented properly.

```py
from pathlib import Path

image_path = Path('images/my-image.jpg')
...
scheduled_event.edit(cover=image_path.read_bytes())
```